# Как реализовать смену страниц по скролу мыши

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, mouse-event

Добрый день. Вот на этом сайте [RBC.ru](http://dreamstudio.dev/page1.php#) есть функционал, который при скролинге мыши меняет страницы новости. Как это сделать? Есть ли пример или реализация?

Answer (score 1):

Смотря как реализовать смену страницы, подгружать новую или менять адрес. А за всем стоит событие `wheelDeltaY` или `deltaY`. По этим событиям можно реализовать задуманное.

```js
window.onmousewheel = function(e) {
    document.querySelector('#mouseevent').innerHTML
        = e.wheelDeltaY > 0 ? '↑ вверх' : '↓ вниз';
}
```

```html
<span id='mouseevent'></span>
```

`deltaY` содержит в себе значение от установленного количества строк прокрутки мыши.
Одна строка равна 33.3, а 3 строки соответственно 100.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]